# Why is it considered a better practice to use anonymous function instead of a function reference as parameter?

Tags: javascript, parameters, anonymous-function

Like this :

```
addEventHandler(document.getElementById('btnAdd'), "click", function() 
   { addNewItem(); }, false);
```

instead of :

```
addEventHandler(document.getElementById('btnAdd'), "click", addNewItem, false);
```

I know it's related to the javascript interpreter(s) working a little bit more. But how?

Comment: In your example there is no point in using an anonymous function.

Comment: Where did you hear that your first example is better practice?

Comment: The first is useful when you need to pass a parameter to `addNewItem` from that current scope. You obviously can't do that with your second example. But I wouldn't call it "better" practice. Another reason to **not** use an anonymous function is when it's inside of a loop and you're calling `addEventHandler` this way. You'd be creating a new function every iteration, when you can easily just reference `addNewItem`, which is created once

Comment: I hear that there : http://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/practical-and-effective-javascript/781-2/transcript : instead of passing in a string, I use the anonymous function and pass in the code that I want to have executed. So the JavaScript interpreter doesn't have to fire up a separate instance of interpreting some code in a completely different scope. I'm just passing in the code that I want called, and this is much, much more efficient."

Comment: I guess that he was talking about a function with parameters...

Comment: @trogne I see. Well I'll have to read that. Another thing I thought of about the difference between these approaches is that passing `addNewItem`'s reference means it will always be called and passed the associated `Event` object, which may or may not be desirable based on how you use `addNewItem` elsewhere. Using your first approach, you control exactly what's passed to the `addNewItem` function (albeit nothing in this example). I literally just came across this problem in my own code and and "have to" change from the second method to the first in one case, although I'm sure I can rearrange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a named function allows:

- shorter, more readable, lines
- descriptive names
- easy reuse of the function elsewhere

Passing an anonymous function that does nothing except call a single other function (as per your example) is just bloat — the verbosity of an inline function expression while still having a named function, it is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: +1, but there's one case where the anon function is necessary: When explicitly need *not* to pass the `event` argument (or similar).

Answer (score 2):

Using a naming function involves :

- more code
- a pollution of the global space
- a less readable code because it isn't obvious that the function isn't used elsewhere

So, provided you don't reuse the function, it's better to use an anonymous one instead of creating a named function.

But that if your code is exactly the one you show, then the anonymous function makes no sense at all. What would be the equivalent anonymous equivalent of the second code is

```
addEventHandler(document.getElementById('btnAdd'), "click", function() {
    // addNewItem implementation
}, false);
```

And if you already have a named function, for example because you reuse it, then don't use an anonymous function just to wrap it.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily pollute the global namespace... The declaration could be in a closure.

Comment: @Jivings well, then you make an external anonymous function just to avoid using an anonymous function as callback... If the function isn't reused that really makes no sense.

Comment: @dystroy — No. Function declarations are scoped. You don't have to use a function expression to scope it, so it wouldn't be anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give my *opinion* and not claim this is a best practice.  I used to always pass references to named functions as arguments instead, and I would never pass small wrapper anonymous functions when I could avoid it.  However, I've moved away from this standard.  Now I pass in references to named functions when I don't suspect there to be much iteration on my function's signature, and I pass in wrapper anonymous functions when I suspect there to be iteration on my function's signature.

I'll use this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steaks/xt73E/) to explain my previous standard, current standard, and why I moved away from my old standard.  In summary, I learned from a few bugs that passing in wrapped anonymous functions can be more refactor safe because you must explicitly code what arguments you're passing into your function.  Still, both patterns have their place.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

//I previously tended to pass in function name references.  However, I recently moved towards
//passing in anonymous functions because I found that pattern to be a bit more refactor safe.
//More specifically, it is more refactor safe when you suspect the signature of our function
//will change.  If you never expect the function's signature to change, then I guess you shouldn't
//need to worry about passing in an anonymous function.

//Because of the way addEventListener uses addNewItem, addNewItem will always receive one 
//paramter: the event object.  Therefore, we are not using addNewItem correct.  It expects one
//argument that is message.  Previously, we were calling addNewItem correctly when it looked like
//addNewItemOld and expected zero arguments.  Click "Add message incorrect" to see the incorrect 
//behaviour
btn.addEventListener("click", addNewItem);

//Now I often to wrap my function calls in anonymous functions because I know exactly what arguments
//I'm passing into my function.  In this case I am explicitely not passing in a message.  Now, we are
//using the addNewItem function correctly
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(e) { addNewItem(); });

//This function has been refactored.  It used to look like addNewItemOld.  The way
//this function's signature has been refactored is particularly interesting.  It now
//has an optional paramter called message.
function addNewItem(message) {
    var span =document.createTextNode(message || "Now nodes have a default message"),
        workspace = document.getElementById("workspace");
    workspace.appendChild(span);
}

function addNewItemOld() {
    var span =document.createTextNode("Every node has the same message"),
        workspace = document.getElementById("workspace");
    workspace.appendChild(span);
}
```